# Python bot on Heroku: Integer out of range (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, telegram

I'm using a Python bot template.

For SQLALCHEMY database, I am using Elephant SQL and app is hosted on Heroku.

When I try to run the Telegram bot, the following error appears on Heroku:

```
 2021-12-09T20:50:06.203420+00:00 app[worker.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) integer out of range

2021-12-09T20:50:06.203421+00:00 app[worker.1]: 

2021-12-09T20:50:06.203421+00:00 app[worker.1]: [SQL: INSERT INTO users (user_id, username) VALUES (%(user_id)s, %(username)s)]

2021-12-09T20:50:06.203421+00:00 app[worker.1]: [parameters: {'user_id': 5077702275, 'username': 'Lena_MilizeBot'}]
```

Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: `5077702275` is to big a value for the column type. Best guess is the column is defined as `integer` and `select 5077702275::int; ERROR:  integer out of range`. Either change the column type to `bigint` or keep the values in the range specified here [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html)

Comment: @Adrian Klaver I edited it but it did not work :(

Comment: Edited what and how? Define 'did not work'? Include error messages.  If you want to get an answer you need to provide detailed information on what you are doing as we are not looking over your shoulder. Add answer as update to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to replace int with [BigInteger](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html) and it worked. As rightly pointed by out Adrian in the comments, we need to use "Bigint" for Postgresql. However, for SQLALCHEMY, value is BigInteger.